# Implementing conv1d with numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, convolution

I am trying to implement tensorflow's conv1d using numpy operations, ignoring strides and padding for now.  I thought I understood it after my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521443/what-is-wrong-with-my-multi-channel-1d-convolution-implemented-in-numpy-compare/59523238?noredirect=1#comment105218154_59523238) but realized today that I was still not getting the right answer when dealing with kernels wider than 1.

So now I am trying to use tflearn as a template because it computes the kernel shape for me.  Now that I understand that the convolution can be computed as a matrix multiplication I am attempting to use the kernel matrix accordingly, but I am not getting the same answer as tflearn.  Examining the source code is quite opaque because it just calls out to tensorflow's dedicated compiled implementations.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
inp = np.arange(10).reshape(1,10,1).astype(np.float32)
filters = 2
width = 3
z = tflearn.conv_1d(inp, filters, width, strides=1, padding='same', bias=False)
s = tf.Session()
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
z1, w = s.run([z, z.W])
print('tflearn output shape', z1.shape)
print('tflearn kernel shape', w.shape)
print('numpy matmul shape', (inp @ w).shape)
```

This indicates that the tflearn kernel puts the width as an extra dimension inserted at the beginning:

```
tflearn output shape (1, 10, 2)
tflearn kernel shape (3, 1, 1, 2)
numpy matmul shape (3, 1, 10, 2)
```

Accordingly the result I get has that extra `3` dimension.  Fine, so how do I correctly reduce it to get the same answer as tensorflow?  I tried summing this dimension, but it is not correct:

```
print('tflearn output:')
print(z1)

print('numpy output:')
print(np.sum(inp @ w, axis=0))
```

gives,

```
tflearn output:
[[[-0.02252221  0.24712706]
  [ 0.49539018  1.0828717 ]
  [ 0.0315876   2.0945265 ]
  [-0.43221498  3.1061814 ]
  [-0.89601755  4.117836  ]
  [-1.3598201   5.129491  ]
  [-1.823623    6.141146  ]
  [-2.2874253   7.152801  ]
  [-2.7512276   8.164455  ]
  [-2.989808    6.7048397 ]]]
numpy output:
[[[ 0.          0.        ]
  [-0.46380258  1.0116549 ]
  [-0.92760515  2.0233097 ]
  [-1.3914077   3.0349646 ]
  [-1.8552103   4.0466194 ]
  [-2.319013    5.0582743 ]
  [-2.7828155   6.069929  ]
  [-3.2466178   7.0815845 ]
  [-3.7104206   8.093239  ]
  [-4.174223    9.104893  ]]]
```

which are clearly different.  `z.W` has of course been initialized to random values so these numbers are random too, but I am looking for the numpy calculation that would make them equal to `z1`, since they are executing the same kernel.  Clearly it is not as simple as `inp @ w`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Okay sorry, I have answered my own question after some thought... THIS is where the sliding window operation comes in that I was trying to introduce in my previous question:

```
y = (inp @ w)
y[0,:,:-2,:] + y[1,:,1:-1,:] + y[2,:,2:,:]
```

gives,

```
array([[[ 0.49539018,  1.0828717 ],
        [ 0.0315876 ,  2.0945265 ],
        [-0.43221498,  3.1061814 ],
        [-0.89601755,  4.117836  ],
        [-1.3598201 ,  5.129491  ],
        [-1.823623  ,  6.141146  ],
        [-2.2874253 ,  7.152801  ],
        [-2.7512276 ,  8.164455  ]]], dtype=float32)
```

which is equal to `z1` ignoring the first and last rows, exactly what I'd expect from a 3-point convolution.

Edit: but I would be much obliged if someone could propose a more succinct / efficient way to express the sliding window.. I thought from my previous question that even the sliding window could be taken into account in the matrix multiplication, so it's unfortunate to need to write the indexing logic explicitly.